# REST API get caller domain or server IP address calling my API URL

Tags: api

I have created an API using REST, I want to know the domain name or server IP address who is calling my API URL,

Let say my url is www.abc.com/webapi/api/c3c/pushdata

and let say someone has created a script to call my URL lets say he is calling my API in his URL: http://www.example.com/call.php

I need to know the domain name "example.com" or "server IP address" so that I can make a check whether this domain is allowed/deny to my call my API.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php then of course this is one of the ways to get the IP address (still depends on where your server is located and your configuration):

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Please note that there are some issues with getting the IP address using this $_SERVER array. I could refer you to the post by Virendra Chandak at [Getting real client IP address in PHP](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/getting-real-client-ip-address-in-php-2/)

My own idea is the fact that **most** variables, values, or data retrieved from the client cannot be **trusted** so dig well for other ways.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends where and how you would like to to get this IP address. Do you need it from source code of your REST API controllers? Then it depends on your language (and framework you are using). Usually it is possible to inject HTTP request object to your controller and get IP from there.

Otherwise you can find IP of caller in some kind of server logs (from HTTP headers).

You should really specify situation and technology stack where you need it.